# passando valor do scope para função javascript

Tags: angularjs

Como passar um `$scope.video_url` para uma função javascript na minha view?

Tenho um service que me retorna o id de um video, e na minha view eu tenho uma infunção javascript que inicia o player do youtube de acordo com esse id, mas como faço para passar esse id para a função?

criei um service, mas não apareceu o video na minha view.

```
myApp.service('youtubeAPI',function(){
    return({
        showMovie:movieYoutube,
    });

    function movieYoutube( video_url ){
        var player, iframe;

        // init player
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '200',
              width: '342',
              videoId: video_url,
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              }
            });
        }

        // when ready, wait for clicks
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            var player = event.target;         
            player.playVideo();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Voce deveria considerar criar um servico em angular e não colocar javascript em sua view. Mas como isso não responde sua pergunta...vou criar uma resposta.

Comment: eu consigo utilizar a api do youtube criando um service?

Comment: A chance é que já deva existir uma implementação para o que voce quer.
https://github.com/cejast/ng-youtube. E eu dei uma dica errada para você. No caso de mexer com a view o correto é utilizar uma directive para manipular o que for necessário no DOM e se comunicar com as informações que existem na view e um Service para se comunicar com o serviço externo que você está utilizando. Por fim, a directive utiliza o service para conseguir os dados necessário e colocá-los na view. A directive também processa as ações que o usuário faz na view referentes a essa directive.

Comment: de acordo com o service quer montei, podera me dar um exemplo, essa coisa de directive ainda não entrou na minha cabeça?

Eu entendi o conceito, que a directive pega as infos da view e o service trabalha no externo.

Nesse service que montei, ele não consegue inicializar a classe `YT.Player` ele acusa `YT.Player is not definied`

Comment: Tem que ver onde e como você está incluindo essa biblioteca do YT.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link que eu te passei com um exemplo de como utilizar o youtube no angular. Ele utiliza um Service pra carregar o script do youtube.

Comment: Vinicius, estou incluindo a bibliotca do YT diretamente no service.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o angular dentro do seu script na view diretamente pois ele é definido globalmente.

```
<div ng-controller="AlgumCtrl" id="ctrlID"></div>
<script>
    function foo(){
        var scope = angular.element('#ctrlID').scope();
        var video_url = scope.video_url;
        //faça algo
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: isso vai pegar o scope que eu setar na div ou todos os scopes do controller?